# Declaring function inside class component in React

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component { 

  getTime() {
    return new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  }
  state = { time: null };

  render() {
    return (
    <div htmlFor="search">
      <label className="search" htmlFor="username">Name Please: </label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
      <button style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', color: 'white'}}> Submit </button>
      <p>{getTime()}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default App;
```

I've been trying to get the time and display it in React but I keep getting errors.
Line 16:11:  'getTime' is not defined  no-undef
But I've been doing just as tutorial told me to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.getTime()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first of all usually we define state in the beginning so just put it before `getTime` function
- second thing - to be able to use functions in class components in react you have to add `this` before so just make it

  `<p>{this.getTime()}</p>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this` keyword for referring to the class and then methods and properties.
So `this.getTime();` should be used.